# Ubuntu 20.04 option not visible in GRUB menu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, gpu, nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver

I have a triple-booted system with Windows, Ubuntu 18.04, and Ubuntu 20.04. Windows OS is installed on my SSD and both the Ubuntu OSs are installed in the HDD in separate partitions. My system used the GRUB inside of my Ubuntu 18.04. So it usually has options to boot into Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04, and Windows

I have an Nvidia 1050Ti GPU with proprietary drivers installed on my Ubuntu OSs. I use `prime-select` utility to switch between Nvidia GPU and Integrated Intel UHD graphics depending on my needs. I was using Nvidia GPU this morning and as my GPU work was over I switched back to Intel UHD graphics using  `sudo prime-select intel` and rebooted my system. When my system rebooted, I could not find Ubuntu 20.04 in my GRUB menu and all I found was Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows OS. I tried to execute `sudo update-grub2` but still the GRUB menu only has Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows.

Any solutions in regards to the above issue? Help will be appreciated.

TIA

[EDIT]

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   2.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/884
loop1    7:1    0   548K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/106
loop2    7:2    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop3    7:3    0 243.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/39
loop4    7:4    0   2.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/160
loop5    7:5    0   704K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/723
loop6    7:6    0  50.4M  1 loop /snap/sublime-text/102
loop7    7:7    0  57.2M  1 loop /snap/sublime-text/97
loop8    7:8    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop9    7:9    0   276K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/708
loop10   7:10   0  64.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop11   7:11   0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop12   7:12   0 295.7M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2344
loop13   7:13   0  61.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/1026
loop14   7:14   0  61.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/975
loop15   7:15   0   2.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/826
loop16   7:16   0   2.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/157
loop17   7:17   0 295.6M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2288
loop18   7:18   0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12159
loop19   7:19   0   548K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/103
loop20   7:20   0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12398
loop21   7:21   0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2066
loop22   7:22   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   127M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 746.4G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 149.5G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:5    0  15.3G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   650M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0   128M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   224G  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0   662M  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0    12G  0 part 
└─sdb6   8:22   0   1.1G  0 part
```

This is the output of `lsblk`

Comment: Have you confirmed that the various installations continue to exist on their devices/partitions?

Comment: How do I confirm that fact? There's no reason for the deletion of Ubuntu OS I did not touch

Comment: Just because there's "no reason" doesn't mean we shouldn't check the basics. Looking at your storage devices and partitions in Disks or with `lsblk` will be enough to confirm that everything still exists. If so, then we can look at manually editing Grub.

Comment: @matigo I have edited the post and have included the output of ```lsblk```

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair